# getting the amount of properties in an object then getting the last one of them in a for loop

Tags: javascript

This should be very easy but I don't know how to do it.

I have this object:

```
var obj = eval(result);
```

Now I want to know how many properties contains to put it in a loop

```
var finalAmount = obj.length;
```

Now I go for the loop

```
for (var i in obj) {
    --- some other code in here
```

Now here the problem I need to do something when the loop reaches the final property of the obj, so this is what Ive tried:

```
if (i+1 == finalamount){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

so basically using the `i` as a pointer to compare it to the var that contains how many items there are and when finding the final one of the loop then do something...

Comment: [Don't use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval!), also obj.length is unlikely to work, unless you eval has returned something like a string or an array. What do you actually want to do with the last item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `i` is not necessarily numeric, and so `i+1` may not give you the desired results.  You should set up a separate counter variable that you increment at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: thanks for that, I used the separate counter and now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case obj must be an Array. If it is not, i+1 throws error.
2. The for-in loop does not ensure any sequence order, even it is an Array, it is only used to iterate unordered properties. You need traditional `for(index=0;index<length;index++)` (if it is an Array)
3. If your obj variable is an Object instead of Array, you can't get "last property" only with object data structure, it must provide more information (property order).